# Raspberry Pi - No-IP DNS does not work

Tags: linux, dns, webserver, raspberry-pi

I want to use my raspberry pi's webserver all over the world. so i decided to use no-ip DNS. I installed everything on my pi and started no ip with `sudo noip2`. I set up everything on the no-ip website (Hostname, address..) as well.

Then i checked with `nslookup` if the connection between my IP-Address and the No-Ip Domain is correct. Everything is ok.
But now when i type in my domain in my explorer, my webserver page does not appear.

I think my router doesn't allow the connection. Can someone help me with the forwarding? And what ports do i need? 
Or what else could be the problem?

Thanks

**EDIT**

Im using a TP-Link TL-WR841N router.  On my RPi i have a Webserver with a mysql database running.

I forward Port 80 to my RPi static IP address 192.168.1.190.

At home i have a router which is connected to the ISP. 1 cable is connected to the WLAN router which im talking about right now. so it is possible that my WLAN router is not the problem, but the router which is connected to the ISP? I have 2 routers because the routers are on different floors.

**SOLUTION**

Its working right now! I had to open the Port 80 also on my second router which is directly connected to the Internet.

Answer (score 1):

I have a raspberry PI working fine with no-ip DNS. To help you first answer this questions please:

1) Could you describe your router (trademark).
2)What port(s) are you using for your application (HTTP: 80, SSH: 22, WEBCAM...)

It's not working due to the forwarding action you mentioned. You need to forward your ports to a private IP that your raspberru PI has in order to access you device.
I also recommend you put a static IP to your raspberry PI, so you wont have to do this every once in a while.

Comment: Im Using just The Webserver ... I have a Homepage Running on my Pi . My Router is a TP-Link router. I also Set up The DNS Setting in my Router Config

Comment: Can you explain what you mean with forwording to private ip? My rpi has a static ip 192.168.1.190

Comment: hello @Mike_NotGuilty use upnpc command on raspberry pi to port forward. provided your ISP is not behind NAT you should be fine running web server on raspberry pi via router public ip address

Answer (score -2):

My Raspberry works fine with noip.

This is a good link for how to set up the DUC client.
http://trzebinski.info/noip-daemon-autostart-after-system-restart-on-raspberry-pi-raspbian/

The link covers getting noip2 to start on boot. It provides a startup script /etc/init.d/noip2 (owned by root with 755 permissions). When this is called with a commandline argument 'start' it will execute:

```
start-stop-daemon --start --exec /usr/local/bin/noip2
```

Finally after creating the script execute:

```
update-rc.d /etc/init.d/noip2 defaults 90
```

Which will ensure the startup script gets run at boot time.